# MySQL Doctrine2 Model Generation

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, doctrine

i am new to ZendFramework and Doctrine.

I am planning to use ZendFramework, Doctrine with DocBlock-Annotations and an existing MySQL-Database.

I want to import the entities from the Database and generate the responding Models through Doctrine.

Is that possible and has someone a link for a tutorial?

Fesp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just answered a very simulair question here:
[Zend 1.11 and Doctrine 2 Auto generate everything needed from already existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833885/zend-1-11-and-doctrine-2-auto-generate-everything-needed-from-already-existing-d/7977343#7977343)

If you have any questions about my post, just ask.

Comment: Thx for the link. There i found the answer that it is not actuall possible but ORMDesigner is working on it

Comment: I am working with ORM Designer to create yml-declarations. With the cli orm:convert-mapping annotation it is possible to create Entities with DocBlockAnnotation from the yml-files

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful a few months back when investigating this topic.

http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/